# Eloquent hasManyThrough with belongsTo on intermediate model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I can get the **hasManyThrough** relation to work fine when the intermediate model has a **hasMany** relation. But what about if the intermediate model has a **belongsTo**, like my StoreProduct model? It would make sense to me that this should be able to work, but it doesn't.

What am I missing?

And how would I get all the Product's Stores (through the "StoreProducts")?

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function storeProducts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\StoreProduct');
    }

    public function stores()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Store', 'App\StoreProduct');
    }
}

class StoreProduct extends Model
{
    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Store');
    }
}

class Store extends Model
{
    public function storeProducts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\StoreProduct');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This relationship type will not work. The `HasManyThroughHasMany` and `HasManyThroughBelongsTo` relationships do not exist. You could write your own to achieve this, or you can work backwards (which I believe is much easier)

```
public function stores()
{
    return Store::whereHas('store_products', function(q){
        return $q->whereHas('product', function(q){
             return $q->where('id', $this->id);
        });
    });
}
```

This function would replace the one in your `Products` model.

Comment: Actually I seem to have solved it by creating a ManyToMany relationship between Product and Store, using StoreProduct as the pivot.
Found the solution here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/hasmanythrough-with-intermediate-belongsto